# Call function again from within ajax in ajax in same function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Sorry for the confusing title, but I couldn't find a better way to explain it..

Here's the situation:

In a function overview(), I grab data with an AJAX call, together with dynamic html.
Inside that AJAX success callback, I perform certain handlers to the new html.
On one of those handlers, I'm posting another AJAX call.

Now, here's my problem: I want to reload the first AJAX call in the second AJAX success callback, to grab my updated data. How do I do this?

Thanks

EDIT: As requested, here's my code (simplified)

```
function overview() {
    var dataString = '...';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get-data.php?',
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('table.table-overview tr.table-heading').after(data);

            $('tr.new-tr span.status').click(function() {
                var dataString = '...';
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'change-status.php?',
                    cache: false,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(response == 'saved') {
                            overview();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**SOLVED**: After some trial and error, replacing my .click() handler to .live('click') made it work!

Comment: By doing so, the same success function will be executed and then the same handlers to the new HTML will be executed again. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you include a code sample of what you've done so far, so that we can get a better idea of your goals?

Comment: @Lorax I've added a code sample

Comment: @ComputerArts A click handler will not be executed again automatically, so it isn't looping or anything, if I'm correct.

Comment: @fishbaitfood Well according to your code, it should be working. But you add a click method $('tr.new-tr span.status'). Depending on what that element is, you might be assigning multiple click events so when you do in fact click on the button, it will execute many times.

Comment: @fishbaitfood, as others have said. There's nothing immediately apparent that would stop your code from working. What happens when you run it?

Comment: Solved with .live('click') for some reason...

With .click() the ajax call wouldn't fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the added sub question, when you run this line of code

```
$('tr.new-tr span.status').click(function() {})
```

you are telling the browser to take every `<span class="status"/>` inside a `<tr class="new-tr"/>` that exists at that moment to attach a click event listener.  `.[live][1]('click')` is different (), there you are saying for every click if it is on a  inside a  then call the function (this works for spans that didn't exist when the live event was bound).  Both approaches are bad inside the success event of the ajax callback.  You can bind the live even listener outside of your ajax calls first and then trust that it will only fire on `<span class="status"/>` inside a `<tr class="new-tr"/>` even if they are created later.

Comment: Forgot about what .live() really does. Thanks for clearing it up again! I'll certainly optimize my code to what you've suggested.

Answer (score 0):

not sure i understand the problem.  But you can chain ajax requests... So you can do something like

```
function func1(){
   $.ajax(){
      url: "whatever.html",
      type: json
      success: func2(data)
   }
 }

 function func2(input){
 //do something with input here

  $.ajax(){
      url: "whatever2.html",
      type: json
      success: func3(data)
   }
  }
```

I'm missing parameters in the ajax requests and the request in func2 could post data from the input parameter 'input'.  Shouldn't be a problem to have multiple ajax requests on the page, you'll just have to worry about when they fire and make sure you pass the correct data from one to another...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are describing.

```js
function ajax1(callback){

    $.ajax({
        ...
    }).done(callback);

}


function ajax2(callback){

    $.ajax({
        ...
    }).done(callback);

}


function overview(){

    loadAjax1(); // start off the ajax loading

}

function loadAjax1(){

    // get first ajax data
    ajax1(function(resp){

        $('body').html(resp) // put the ajax data in your dom, attach your handlers and such


        // find certain element to bind second ajax call
        $('body.find-your-item').click(function(){

            // when clicked, perform second ajax call, and on callback, recall intial ajax load
            ajax2(loadAjax1);
        });

    })

}
```

Comment: Yeah, your code looks like it should work. Have you tested it? 

In my example code I broke the sections apart to make it cleaner and to allow better extensibility later. Having separate functions means you can have other areas in your code call the same method without stepping on other code.